# variable declared in global scope is not being recognised by function

Tags: javascript, node.js, global

the declaration of variable name = michelle in global scope is not being recognised by function sayNameForAll(), please let me know what is the issue.

```
function sayNameForAll() {
console.log(this.name);
}


var person1 = {
name: "Nicholas",
sayName: sayNameForAll
};


var person2 = {
name: "Greg",
sayName: sayNameForAll
};


var name = "Michael";

person1.sayName(); 
person2.sayName(); 
sayNameForAll();
```

[this is the output of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzGB0.png)

Answer (score 2):

It is working as expected in this script, the this variable can be changed in three ways:

- when you call it inside of an object in that case would get the
  object .
- When you use a constructor, class function.
- And when you    use call(), apply(), or bind(); methods.

Other wise will get the global object...

```js
function sayNameForAll() {
console.log(this.name);
}


var person1 = {
name: "Nicholas",
sayName: sayNameForAll
};


var person2 = {
name: "Greg",
sayName: sayNameForAll
};


var name = "Michael";

person1.sayName(); 
person2.sayName(); 
sayNameForAll();
```

Comment: Do you think the issue here is may be due to hoisting?

Comment: Not at all because at the time you call the sayNameForAll() the variable Michelle already exists in the global object..

Comment: Yes thats what i noticed too but what if it is declared after `sayNameForAll();`

Comment: It will still work because the execution of javascript is done in two phases, first the functions and variables take and space in memory, and after that the javascript execution takes place.. you can try moving it..

Comment: Check how js is executed https://cedric-dumont.com/2015/10/31/compilation-and-execution-phases-of-simple-javascript-code/

Comment: hey @RenzoCC, thanks mate, but issue is when i am running it in a node environment i get undefined object, however when i am running code snippet here on stackoverflow it is working as expected. any idea what that would be? Thanks

Answer (score -1):

The issue is within the context you run your function. In 2 first runs it goes inside context of the object, where you have 'this' internal variable. For the last one - you're trying to output 'this.name' but inside you've had only 'name'